# Integrate a SymPy expression with a complex factor which does not involve x

Tags: python, sympy

I want to integrate complex functions with sympy.integrate. I realized that it takes too much time (at least I stopped process after 2.5 hours).

I am planning to give an equation to the program as simply as possible. 
Lets assume I have a function :

```
alpha*x**(-rho/(rho - 1))*(-gamma*l*rho + gamma*l - gamma*pi*rho + gamma*pi - l*rho - pi*rho)/(gamma*mu)
```

I only part I will integrate is

```
MainPart = x**(-rho/(rho - 1))

IntegMainPart=sympy.integrate(MainPart)
```

and rest are only parameters and they will be

```
Rest=alpha*(-gamma*l*rho + gamma*l - gamma*pi*rho + gamma*pi - l*rho - pi*rho)/(gamma*mu)
```

So is it possible that i can take only important part and integrate it and than multiple with rest like

```
IntegMainPart*Rest
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy is capable of correctly handling the factors that do not involve the variable of integration. You should not need to remove them manually. Here is how this integral works for me.

```
from sympy import symbols, pi, integrate
x, alpha, gamma, mu, rho, l = symbols('x, alpha, gamma, mu, rho, l')
expr = alpha*x**(-rho/(rho - 1))*(-gamma*l*rho + gamma*l - gamma*pi*rho + gamma*pi - l*rho - pi*rho)/(gamma*mu)
print(integrate(expr, x))
```

SymPy 1.3 prints the integral at once.

```
alpha*x**(-rho/(rho - 1) + 1)*(-gamma*l*rho + gamma*l - pi*gamma*rho + pi*gamma - l*rho - pi*rho)/(gamma*mu*(-rho/(rho - 1) + 1))
```